# C++ help - leaking data from a linked lists and segmentation errors

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list

I am learning how to create linked lists in C++ .  I am currently having trouble with my code leaking memory onto the heap and giving me segmentation errors.  I just can't figure out how to fix the problem.  Any help would be much appreciated.
I've tried looking at other questions with similar problems but I can't seem to figure out how to translate the responses into my own code.  I don't know why this particular problem vexes me this much - very frustrating.

This is the header file that gives me the necessary functions to create, asteroid.h:

```
#ifndef ASTEROID
#define ASTEROID

#include "point.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


struct PointNode {
private:
  static int counter;
public:
  Point data;
  PointNode* next;

  PointNode (Point p, PointNode* nxt = 0);

  ~PointNode ();

  static void report();

};

class Asteroid {


  PointNode* first;


public:
  /**
     Create an asteroid 
   */
  Asteroid ();

  Asteroid (const Asteroid& a);
  Asteroid& operator= (const Asteroid& a);
  ~Asteroid() {delete first;}



  /**
     Add a vertex to an asteroid. Vertices must be added "in order"
     either moving clockwise or counter-clockwise around the perimeter
     of the asteroid.
  */
  void addVertex (Point p);


  /**
     Move the asteroid by this amount
  */
  void moveBy (double deltaX, double deltaY);


  /**
     Is this asteroid colliding with another?
  */
  bool isCollidingWith (const Asteroid& aster);


  /**
     Compute the center of gravity of the asteroid (the "average"
     of all the vertices)
   */
  Point getCenter() const;


  void print (std::ostream& out);

private:

  // You don't have to have the following, but it makes it easier to
  // implement isCollidingWith


  /**
     Is point p inside this asteroid?
   */
  bool contains (Point p) const;

};


#endif
```

The PointNode.cpp:

```
#include "asteroid.h"


int PointNode::counter = 0;

PointNode::PointNode (Point p, PointNode* nxt)
  : data(p), next(nxt)
{
  ++counter;
}

PointNode::~PointNode () {delete next; --counter;}

void PointNode::report()
{
  using namespace std; 
  if (counter > 0)
    cout << "Your code is leaking memory on the heap." << endl;
  else if (counter < 0)
    cout << "Your code has corrupted the heap." << endl;
}
```

And the asteroid.cpp, which is the file I am editing and the one giving me trouble:

```
#include "asteroid.h"
#include "line.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/**
   Create an asteroid with the indicated number of vertices.
*/
Asteroid::Asteroid ()
    : first()
{
}

Asteroid::Asteroid (const Asteroid& a)
{ first = NULL;

while (a.first->next != NULL)
{ cout << "In the while loop of the copy constructor, about to add a vertex." << endl;
 addVertex(a.first->data);
 cout << "Added a vertex." << endl;
}

    print(cout);
    delete first;
}
Asteroid& Asteroid::operator= (const Asteroid& a)
{
    if (this != &a)
{ first = NULL;

while (a.first->next != NULL)
{ cout << "In the while loop of the assignment operator, about to add a vertex." << endl;
 addVertex(a.first->data);
 cout << "Added a vertex." << endl;
}

    print(cout);
    delete first;
}
    return *this;
}
/**
     Add a vertex to an asteroid. Vertices must be added "in order"
     either moving clockwise or counter-clockwise around the perimeter
     of the asteroid.
  */
void Asteroid::addVertex (Point p)
{
    PointNode* newNode = new PointNode(p, NULL);
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Adding vertex from null" << endl;
        first = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Adding onto end " << endl;
        PointNode* current = first;
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
            current->next = newNode;
        }
    }
}

/**
     Move the asteroid by this amount
  */
void Asteroid::moveBy (double deltaX, double deltaY)
{
    PointNode* current = first;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        current->data.x += deltaX;
        current->data.y += deltaY;
        current = current->next;
    }
}


/**
     Is this asteroid colliding with another?
  */
bool Asteroid::isCollidingWith (const Asteroid& aster)
{
    cout << "Bool isCollidingWith starts" << endl;
    bool collision = false;
    PointNode* current = first;
    cout << "Pointnode current declared as " << current->data.x << "," << current->data.y << endl;
    while ((!collision) && (current->next != NULL))
    {
        collision = aster.contains(current->data);
        current = current-> next;
    }
    return collision;
}


/**
     Compute the center of gravity of the asteroid (the "average"
     of all the vertices)
   */
Point Asteroid::getCenter() const
{
    Point c (0.0, 0.0);
    int placecount = 0;
    PointNode* current = first;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        c.x += current->data.x;
        c.y += current->data.y;
        current = current->next;
        placecount++;
    }
    c.x = c.x / (placecount);
    c.y = c.y / (placecount);
    return c;
}


bool Asteroid::contains (Point p) const
{  Point c = getCenter();
    // p is inside the asteroid if it is on the same side as c of each
    //  border segment
    PointNode* current = first;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        if (current->next == NULL)
        {
            LineSegment line (current->data, first->data);
            if (!line.onSameSide(p, c))
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            LineSegment line (current->data, current->next->data);
            if (!line.onSameSide(p, c))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}



void Asteroid::print (std::ostream& out)
{
    out << "[";
    PointNode* current = first;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {   out << ", ";
        current->data.print (out);
        //Don't forget to advance your conditional
        current = current->next;
    }
    out << "]";
}
```

I've been at this for a few days now and haven't been making much progress.  I continually get a segmentation fault at the while loop line of the copy constructor for Asteroid, and the program dumps after that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should check `a.first != NULL` before accessing `a.first->next`.

Comment: Also, your `addVertex` should have `current->next = newNode` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is wrong in your `addVertex` method. You should add the node after the while loop not inside the while loop, like this

```
void Asteroid::addVertex (Point p)
{
    PointNode* newNode = new PointNode(p, NULL);
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Adding vertex from null" << endl;
        first = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Adding onto end " << endl;
        PointNode* current = first;
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

The point of the while loop is to find the last node in the list. Once you've found that you exit the while loop and add the new node there.

Comment: Thanks! Now it runs infinitely though, outputting the isCollidingWith statement over and over until I force shut down the program.  Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: @kingkahn If you don't figure it out yourself you should post a new question. Obviously you would need to include the code where isCollidingWith is being called from.